# React Recoil state not being reset properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recoiljs

I have some recoil state, that i want to reset.

```
import { useRecoilValue, useResetRecoilState, useSetRecoilState } from 'recoil';
...
  //should be used for flushing the global recoil state, whenever a user submits an invoice
  const resetLabelInvoiceState = useResetRecoilState(labelInvoiceState);
  const resetMetaDataState = useResetRecoilState(metadataState);
  const resetGlobalAnnotationsState = useResetRecoilState(globalAnnotationState)
```

I have made function, that i suppoes to reset all the states like this. I have both tried with and without the reset function.

```
const flushRecoilState = () =>{
     console.log('flushed state')
     return(
    resetLabelInvoiceState(),
    resetMetaDataState(),
    resetGlobalAnnotationsState()
     )
   }
```

```
...
        flushRecoilState()
        return history.push('/historyinvoices')
...
```

When i check the state it is not reset. Is it because the `useResetRecoilState´ is not working properly from the library, is not implemented properly, or is there some other problem.

I could just use the regular `useRecoilState` hook, and just set the state back to the default value.

Does anybody know why this could be?

Comment: Could you share a minimal CodeSandbox to play with, please? 

Comment: Why are you doing `return(resetLabelInvoiceState(), resetMetaDataState(), resetGlobalAnnotationsState())`? It does not make sense, all the functions are called but just the result of the first one is returned. More: the `useResetRecoilState` returns nothing if I remember correctly 

Comment: When do you check the reset value? This is a async operation. Calling the reset function returned by the hook does not immediately propagate the change to every single subscribed component. It works just like set state in vanilla React.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, it turns out to be my own fault. Just put it here for future reference.

My problem was that I changed the set method in the selector, if you customized the set method, you need to check if the incoming value is a `DefaultValue`.

```js
const targetYear = selector({
  key: 'targetYear',
  get: ({get}) => get(targetYearAtom),
  set: ({set, get}, method) => {
    const currentTargetYear = get(targetYearAtom);
    switch(method) {
      case 'prevYear':
        set(targetYearAtom, currentTargetYear - 1);
        return;
      case 'nextYear':
        set(targetYearAtom, currentTargetYear + 1);
        return;
      default:
        if (method instanceof DefaultValue) {
          set(targetYearAtom, method);
        }
        return;
    }
  },
})
```